# Correct structure and way of website versioning

Tags: version-control

Recently I use GIT to version my website. It makes it all really easy to see how my project develops and I always have save backups on different places on the web.

Now my main question is if it is recommended to version your whole root of the website. I have a basic structure that looks something like this:

```
/httpdocs
  /config
  /media
  /application
  index.php
  .htaccess
```

1) Should I use the /httpdocs folder to version, or should I use the content of the folder.

2) Is it recommended to version the media folder.

In the media version I have several images for the overall layout, and some other images for  the website. These images can be quite large. I work on these images from time to time and so they change. I hardly never need the old image again, so is this not just taking up precious storage space.

I would highly appreciate just some basic recommendation on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I have to say that I mainly work with SVN and desktop apps but the ideas should be roughly the same.

1. I would not add httpdocs to source
   control, just the contents of
   httpdocs, unless there are
   references to the folder within your
   content, e.g relative paths that
   specifically have httpdocs in them.
2. I would version the media folder,
   simply because I can checkout/export
   a particular version of the web site
   immediately with the exact images as
   of that version.

   Sometimes, the dimensions of the
   same image might have differed
   between versions so it's always good
   to get that exact image used by a
   particular version of he website.

   Besides, you'll never know when a client wants to rollback to a previous version of an image.

Answer (score 2):

What are you worried about?

Version control seldom introduces a disk space problem that wouldn't have existed otherwise.  If you're just worried about *potential* problems, I'd file this under [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).  If you have a real disk space issue, I'd buy another disk.  Disks are cheap.  It doesn't sound like you're changing the image often enough for this to be cost-prohibitive.

Comment: +1: Storage space is cheap. Wasting developer time due to missing versions of source code and associated assets is not.